# Best practices for abstract factory construction that fails

Tags: c++, c++11

### Background

Suppose we have an implementation of the abstract factory which is invoked as follows:

```
std::string ObjectName = "An Object Name";
std::string Args = "Argument passed directly to constructor by the factory";

std::unique_ptr<MyBaseClass> MyPtr(ObjectFactory::Instance().Construct(ObjectName,Args));
```

The factory uses a `std::map` to turn `"An Object Name"` into a constructor, which itself takes a `std::string` as an argument. The idea is that the user knows more about the constructed objects than I do, so I should get out of the way and let the user pass any information they want to the constructor.

### Question

This works fine when `Args` is in exactly the form expected but I don't know the most idiomatic way of handling duff inputs. What should happen if a user supplies an invalid argument string?

I can think of the following:

- have the object's constructor throw an exception
- require the object provides a `bool Validate(std::string x)` method, which checks whether `x` is a valid argument string
- Have the factory use the default constructor, and then call an initialisation method afterwards (begs the question: what if the init method fails?)
- Set a `bool` member variable which, if true, means "this object is not in a sane state"
- Some other option I've not thought of

Comment: Why is it related to a factory? Assume you know the needed type at compile-time and directly create an object: `MyDerivedClass class(Args);` You will have all the same problems, so the answers will be the same?

Comment: The specific child class required is not known until run time, so the factory approach is indicated.

Comment: I see, but all your problems are not specific to this situation. All the problems are more general. Be it factory or not, the answers will be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Throw an exception. You're constructing an object (albeit in a different way than just `new`), failure is an exception that needs to be handled if it can happen.

"Solution 2" has nothing to do with handling this issue, it's more of a *how* to determine bad input. For such it can be an acceptable solution, but again it has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Solution 3 leaves the object in an indeterminate state in case of failure, which is unacceptable.

Solution 4 is another way to do it, and the only way if you don't have exception support in your language, but we do. Exceptions in this case are strictly better in my opinion because failing to construct an object is an action so destructive it should *require* alternative code or the program to die.

Comment: You had me at "Throw an exception"

Comment: Basic rhetoric, start with the point then go in details as necessary :)

Answer (score 2):

The first solution is the standard solution for constructor failure.
Solution #2 and #4 are pretty error prone (user might forget to check)
Solution #3 doesn't solve the problem

If you're making a library or just writing code that might be re-used in a "no exceptions allowed" environment, you could consider returning std::unique_ptr{nullptr}. Even if it is also error prone, that's the other standard way of handling construction failure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to return a nullptr.

Comment: The _easiest_ is without a doubt to do `return nullptr`. Not short thereafter comes `throw MyException()`. Following them are a plethora of permutations of different techniques. Which one is best is an Emacs-vs-Vim war... :)

Answer (score -3):

What ever you do, do not throw an exception from a constructor (as per Item #10 in More effective C++), as the destructor will not be called. It leads to newbie memory leaks and forces users to worry about exception handling.

I would just assert and return a Null Object, with dummy factory method implementations, or return nullptr.

Comment: The destructor of MyBaseClass will not be called, but the destructor for each constructed item will be called, which is most often good enough.

Comment: @Wesley, if all members of the class are properly RAII objects, then their destructors _are_ called and #10 in MEC++ is not in play.

Comment: That was not my point, if you throw in a constructor, perhaps after allocating memory or opening a file handle for instance, and count on RAII, then you will be trouble, as the destructor for the same object is not called to clean it up!! Never throw in a constructor.

Comment: @Wesley, my point was that if you move all such operations to their own RAII objects, they _will_ be cleaned up.

Comment: It's actually considered _best practice_ to throw exceptions from constructors on failure. You've probably meant, _"Don's ever trow exceptions from destructors"_.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ. Please show me where this is a best practice. At best I can see it being a subject of debate. I cannot think of anything worse than having to wrap every construction of an object with a try/catch, with the fear it may throw an exception.

Comment: @WesleyShillingford See the upvoted and accepted answers. It's seriously not _bad practice_ to throw from constructor functions. Who told you that?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ. I could not care about who upvoted, exceptions are bad in general (ask Google, they don't use them). Doing this means that any users of the code have to deal with them. It's a constraint I'd rather not have to deal with.

Comment: @WesleyShillingford I don't understand what you're trying to tell me? In general exceptions are fine, and it's encouraged to use them when encountering exceptional situations, no matter if these occur in constructors or other functions. The only place where throwing exceptions is considered bad is using them with destructors. So what?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ What I'm trying to tell you is that one of the biggest software firms doesn't use exceptions! Just read their coding guidelines.Not sure why you weren't able to comprehend that from what I said, and I'm done wasting my time on you.

Comment: @WesleyShillingford _"What I'm trying to tell you is that one of the biggest software firms doesn't use exceptions!"_ And these fail upon just using exceptions correctly. I give a f*ck about google code and their policies. They have many weird restrictions and policies, that have nothing to do with the c++ standard recommendations, but clumsy compatibility issues.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ Ubisoft don't use exceptions either. And they are much more successful, and able to give advice than most people here (including yourself). And I don't give a f*ck about your policies ,,!,,(-_^),,!,,

Comment: @WesleyShillingford They're not _mine_ bub!